# VBA code to delete range based on variable - running slowly

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using this code to delete a range, where a certain cell in the last column (AA) of that range is equal to a variable specified elsewhere in the worksheet (K2).

The code uses `Shift: xlUp` to remove that data and shift the rest of the data upwards.

All of this is done one row at a time until the condition is no longer true.

The only issue is that this runs quite slowly - even for 25-30 rows of data being deleted, one at a time. What can I do to speed it up?

```
Sub UncommitSession()
Dim WHAT_TO_FIND As String
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim FoundCell As Excel.Range
Dim iVal As Integer

iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AA5:AA800"), Range("K2"))

WHAT_TO_FIND = Range("K2")

For i = 1 To iVal
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  Set FoundCell = ws.Range("AA:AA").Find(what:=WHAT_TO_FIND, lookat:=xlWhole)
  If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    Range("Q" & FoundCell.Row & ":AA" & FoundCell.Row).Delete Shift:=xlUp
  Else
    MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " not found in session archive.")
  End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: did you try `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the begining of your code ?

Comment: `application.calculation=xlmanualcalculation`    then code, then set back to automatic

Comment: perhaps if you were to store the item in memory (as an array) then search on that instead of searching the worksheet range object it may be faster. Little more complicated but doesn't have to access the worksheet for searching each cell.

Comment: You could move `Set ws = Activesheet` outside of your loop as it really only needs to be set once.  Won't save much time though.

Comment: I did have `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` but this does nothing to improve the speed, it only hides the operations.

Comment: The way to speed up the process is avoiding deleting the value for each loop,  turning off automatic calculation or screen updating will not save you in this case. You need to delete them all at once (see z32a7ul's answer).

Answer (score 1):

I think the fastest solution is to set up autofilters, select the visible rows and delete them.
Here is a sample from one of my projects, which uses the auto filter through list objects:

```
Dim lstTable As ListObject: Set lstTable = rngTarget.Worksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rngTarget, , xlYes)
lstTable.Range.AutoFilter colFilter, varValue
lstTable.DataBodyRange.EntireRow.Delete
```

In the above you need to change rngTarget to refer to your table, colFilter to refer to be the column number of AA and varValue to be WHAT_TO_FIND.

**Update**

Customizing it to your code:

```
Sub UncommitSession()
    Dim ewsTarget As Worksheet: Set ewsTarget = ActiveSheet
    Dim varValue As String: varValue = ewsTarget.Range("K2").Value
    Dim rngTarget As Range: Set rngTarget = ewsTarget.Range("A5:AA800")
    Dim lstTable As ListObject: Set lstTable = rngTarget.Worksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rngTarget, , xlYes)
    lstTable.Range.AutoFilter ewsTarget.Range("AA1") - ewsTarget.Range("A1") + 1, varValue
    lstTable.TableStyle = vbNullString
    lstTable.DataBodyRange.EntireRow.Delete
    lstTable.Unlist
End Sub
```

I don't have, however, your Workbook, so I cannot test it.

Comment: Thanks, can you show your code in the context of a complete sub, as I can't quite get it to work.